# Getting a pixel color number from an indexed PNG file in golang

Tags: go, graphics, png

Golang let you get the RGBA value for each pixels of a png file by using png.Decode and img.At:

```
file, _ := os.Open("file.png")
img, err := png.Decode(file)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
for y := 0; y < img.Bounds().Max.Y; y++ {
    for x := 0; x < img.Bounds().Max.X; x++ {
        color := img.At(x, y)
        fmt.Printf("%v", color)
    }
}
```

Will return {91 71 0 255}{91 71 2 255}{92 72 1 255} (...) How to get each color number instead?

Comment: can you give a concrete example of what you mean by "color number"  ?

Comment: With pixelart software and on more or less vintage computers, you have a limited palette with RGB values, and you refer each pixels by a color number, which points to the palette...

Comment: above you show color of a pixel in rgba as {91 71 0 255}   so what would be the "color number" of that pixel ?   are you looking for a  triplet equivalent in hex as in conversion from rgb of   85,255,85  into its hex of  #55FF55   ?

Comment: The color number would be its rank inside the palette. https://www.jessechapo.com/posts/Developers-Guide-to-Images.html

Comment: that link you mention explaining color number is a broken link